# SQL - Convert column data type from varchar to bigint with dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Question:** 
Without losing any data, how can I:
 
**#1.** Convert column data type from Varchar to Bigint?

Let's say:

table1.my_ID = "12345"  // default is varchar

change into:

table1.my_ID = 12345  // convert to bigint

**#2.** ..and how can I do this if my table has a lot of dependencies?

I tried ALTER TABLE and ALTER COLUMN:

```
ALTER TABLE [MY_DATABASE].[dbo].table1
ALTER COLUMN my_ID BIGINT
```

and I got these:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'PK_table1' is dependent on column 'my_ID'.
>   Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'FK_table2_table1' is dependent on column 'my_ID'.
>   Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'FK_table3_table1' is dependent on column 'my_ID'.
>   ..blah blah..
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN my_ID failed because one or more
>   objects access this column.

Please help. 
Thanks!

Comment: To help people answer this quickly, any chance you can provide a SQL-Fiddle of your schema, etc?

Comment: Best is to drop those constraints, create new column as int, update table with populating new column with old column, recreate constraint and drop varchar column

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
CREATE TABLE A (
ID VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL ,
AA VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
)
GO
CREATE TABLE #B (
ID BIGINT  NOT NULL ,
BB VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO A VALUES ('123','AAA');

INSERT INTO #B 
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,ID) , AA FROM A;

SELECT * FROM A;
SELECT * FROM #B;

ALTER TABLE A
ALTER COLUMN ID BIGINT NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO A
SELECT * FROM #B;

SELECT * FROM A;
SELECT * FROM #B;

DROP TABLE #B;
```

Or you can try :

```
CREATE TABLE A (
ID VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL ,
AA VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO A VALUES ('123','AAA');

ALTER TABLE A
ADD C1 BIGINT ;

UPDATE A
SET C1 = (SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT , ID) FROM A);

SELECT * FROM A;

ALTER TABLE A
DROP COLUMN ID;

ALTER TABLE A
ALTER COLUMN C1 BIGINT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE A 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (C1);

EXEC sp_rename 'A.C1' , 'ID' , 'COLUMN';
```